# Need to add text in response token as 'Bearer <token > to request of other end point in soapui

Tags: json, api, soapui

I am trying to pass the Bearer Token from one response to other request by using property transfer, although need to add text "Bearer" & a space with token in SOAPUI using json path.

like my first endpoint response is "{"accessToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwZXJtaXNzaW9uc"}

and by using $.accessToken i got the access token value in property transfer but i want to add a string and a space to this token like " Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwZXJtaXNzaW9uc" as a request for the other endpoint.

Property transfer in soap ui ..so i used token dynamically everytime